# Sinusoidal electric potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

An electrical potential changes sinusoidal with a frequency of $60 Hz$ according to the relationship

$V = V_{max} \sin [2\pi (60 Hz)t]$

With $V_{max} = 150 V$, considering the time interval of 1 second the argument of the sine function becomes

$\sin (120\pi) = 0.587$

So

$V = 150 V \cdot 0.587 = 88.2 V$

Is it all right, or have I made any mistake in converting radians to degrees?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sin of any integer multiple of pi (radians) is 0.0. The argument as represented in your expression is already in radians.  Frequency in Hertz is expressed in cycles per second. There are two pi radians in a cycle. The factor of two-pi converts cycles to radians.

Degrees never show up, ignore them.